# How capture all the messages sent to a window using a WH_CBT hook and the WndProc?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm building a logging system inside of a dll, the principal task of this will be trap some specific windows messages of a target application and do some tasks.  But unfortunately only one message is trapped by the `WndProc` method (`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`).  What I'm missing? Why not all the windows messages are written to the log?

This is a minimal sample code to demostrate the issue

## DLL

```
library LogDll;

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.IOUtils,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

{$R *.res}

type
  TLogInspector = class
  private
    WndHandle: THandle;
    ProcAddrInst: Pointer;
    OrgWndProc: Pointer;
  protected
    function CallOrgWndProc(Message: TMessage): LRESULT;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); virtual;
  public
    constructor Create(AHandle: THandle); virtual;
  end;

var
  MainHook: HHook;
  Log : TLogInspector;

function TLogInspector.CallOrgWndProc(Message: TMessage): LRESULT;
begin
  Result := CallWindowProc(OrgWndProc, WndHandle, Message.Msg, Message.wParam,  Message.lParam);
end;

constructor TLogInspector.Create(AHandle: THandle);
begin
  OrgWndProc := Pointer(GetWindowLongPtr(AHandle, GWL_WNDPROC));
  ProcAddrInst := MakeObjectInstance(WndProc);
  WndHandle := AHandle;
  SetWindowLongPtr(WndHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, LONG_PTR(ProcAddrInst));
end;

procedure TLogInspector.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  //log the current message
  TFile.AppendAllText('C:\Delphi\log.txt', 'WndProc '+IntToStr(Message.Msg)+sLineBreak);
  //call the org WndProc 
  Message.Result := CallOrgWndProc(Message);
end;


function HookCallBack(nCode: Integer;  _WPARAM: WPARAM; _LPARAM: LPARAM): LRESULT;  stdcall;
var
  lpClassName : array [0 .. 256] of Char;
begin
  if nCode = HCBT_CREATEWND then
    begin
      GetClassName(_WPARAM, lpClassName, 256);
      if lpClassName = 'TForm1' then
        Log:=  TLogInspector.Create(_WPARAM);
    end;

  Result := CallNextHookEx(MainHook, nCode, _WPARAM, _LPARAM);
end;


procedure InitLog; stdcall;
begin
  MainHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, @HookCallBack, 0, GetCurrentThreadId);
end;

procedure DoneLog; stdcall;
begin
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(MainHook);
end;

exports
   InitLog, DoneLog;

begin
end.
```

## Application

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

  procedure InitLog; stdcall;  external 'LogDll.dll' name 'InitLog';
  procedure DoneLog; stdcall;  external 'LogDll.dll' name 'DoneLog';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}



initialization
 InitLog;
finalization
 DoneLog;
end.
```

Comment: WH_CBT hooks only trap specific window events. You probably want a WH_GETMESSAGE hook.

Comment: The WH_CBT hook, only is used to detect when a window is created, the messages are traped replacing the original `WndProc` using the `SetWindowLongPtr` function.

Comment: First of all, you need a global hook if you're targeting other applications.

Comment: Then you'll need to keep track of window handles and window procedures of an application. You can't overwrite your window procedure pointer or window handle every time an application creates a window. You don't want that application's top level window messages to be delivered to an edit control window procedure for instance..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, this is just a basic sample to demostrate the issue, the real log dll keeps a list with the handles and windows proc. but the result is the same. only one message is trapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test case is replacing the window procedure too early. The OS' notifying the hook with window creation before delivering the first message to the actual window's window procedure causes your replacing the window procedure before VCL has finalized setting the window procedure of the form. The below is a summary of key events how your window procedure is replaced by the VCL's:

- In project, VCL sets initial window procedure of the form to `InitWndProc` in 'controls'.
- In project, VCL calls `CreateWindowHandle`, which in turn calls `CreateWindowEx`.
- In dll, the OS notifies your hook that a window is about to be created and you subclass the window procedure.
- In dll, the replaced window procedure is called with the first message (`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`).
- In project, `InitWndProc` is delivered the same message in which the window procedure is replaced with the `MainWndProc` method of the form.
- In dll, the re-replaced window procedure is never called again.

Set a breakpoint in the dll on `SetWindowLongPtr` and a breakpoint in the project on `SetWindowLong` in `InitWndProc` in 'controls.pas' to see it in action.

With a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook, you might not need to subclass the window to be able to log messages sent to it. E.g.:

```
function HookCallBack(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  lpClassName : array [0 .. 256] of Char;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(MainHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
  if nCode >= 0 then begin
    GetClassName(PCWPStruct(lParam).hwnd, lpClassName, 256);
    if lpClassName = 'TForm1' then
      TFile.AppendAllText('C:\Delphi\log.txt', 'WndProc ' +
          IntToStr(PCWPStruct(lParam).message) + sLineBreak);
  end;
end;

procedure InitLog; stdcall;
begin
  MainHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, @HookCallBack, 0, GetCurrentThreadId);
end;
```

But if you have to, you can do it f.i. in `WM_NCCREATE`.

Comment: Thanks very much, For diagnose the cause of the issue. Do you have any workaround? or I'm out of luck using this kind of hook to intercept the messages?

Comment: @Salvador - I guess a CALLWNDPROC[RET] hook might fit better.

Comment: Thanks very much, using the `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook does the trick.